Flutter webview is not affected by system font size
I don't knoow if I'm missing something, but I'm using webview_flutter plugin (also with webview_flutter_android and webview_flutter_wkwebview), and i have struggles with accessbility font size. Font size in webview on iOS doesn't change when I change it in system settings. Android works well. Do you have any suggestinos ?
I tried to build also example app from webview_flutter_plugin, but there is the same issue.
